# JSON returns undefined. (made via laravel controller)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, undefined

hello I have a json array when I execute  `$('tbody').html(data.table_data);`
in my ajax I get the following return

```
[{"id":28,"fname":"tester","lname":"testlast","phone":"00000000","email":"test@email.com","address":"Tester 10","country":"TesterCountry","city":"TesterTown","bday":"2222-02-22","username":"admin","password":"1234","access":"Admin","created_at":"2018-10-13 16:34:22","updated_at":"2018-10-14 12:50:26"},{"id":29,"fname":"tester2","lname":"tester2last","phone":"11000000","email":"email2@test2.com","address":"Testaria 22","country":"TEsterio","city":"Testeriontiown","bday":"8812-09-08","username":"admin","password":"1234","access":"admin","created_at":"2018-10-14 09:16:50","updated_at":"2018-10-14 12:51:26"}][{"id":28,"fname":"tester","lname":"testlast","phone":"00000000","email":"test@email.com","address":"Tester 10","country":"TesterCountry","city":"TesterTown","bday":"2222-02-22","username":"admin","password":"1234","access":"Admin","created_at":"2018-10-13 16:34:22","updated_at":"2018-10-14 12:50:26"},{"id":29,"fname":"tester2","lname":"tester2last","phone":"11000000","email":"email2@test2.com","address":"Testaria 22","country":"TEsterio","city":"Testeriontiown","bday":"8812-09-08","username":"admin","password":"1234","access":"admin","created_at":"2018-10-14 09:16:50","updated_at":"2018-10-14 12:51:26"}]
```

and with data.total_data I get the number from all the total records I have

ok So whenever I try to output this data  *id:28,fname:tester etc I get undefined.

the code is the following .

```
   function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('index.action') }}",
            method:'GET',
            data:{query:query},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data)
            {
                var client_data = '';
                $.each(data,function (key,value) {
                    client_data += '<tr>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.id +'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.fname+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.lname+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.email+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.phone+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.address+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.country+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.city+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.bday+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.username+'</td>';
                    client_data += '</tr>';
                })


                  $('tbody').html(cleint_data);

                $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);

            }
        })
    }
```

Edit: I dont know how to provide you with an actual response so I do the next best thing. Ill show you how I generate it. maybe that's where my problem is

```
function action(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $output = '';
        $query = $request->get('query');
        if ($query != '') {
            $data = DB::table('users')->
            where('fname', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('lname', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('phone', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('address', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('country', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('city', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('bday', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('username', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('access', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->get();
        } else {
            $data = DB::table('users')
                ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
                ->get();
        }
        $total_row = $data->count();
        if ($total_row > 0) {
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $output .= $data;
            }
        } else {
            $output = '
   <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="13">No Data Found</td>
   </tr>
   ';
        }
        $datas = array(
            'table_data' => $output,
            'total_data' => $total_row
        );

        echo json_encode($datas);
    }
}
```

edit Here is the json output

```
 {table_data: "[{"id":28,"fname":"tester","lname":"testlast","pho…14 09:16:50","updated_at":"2018-10-14 12:51:26"}]", total_data: 2}
table_data: "[{"id":28,"fname":"tester","lname":"testlast","phone":"00000000","email":"test@email.com","address":"Tester 10","country":"TesterCountry","city":"TesterTown","bday":"2222-02-22","username":"admin","password":"1234","access":"Admin","created_at":"2018-10-13 16:34:22","updated_at":"2018-10-14 12:50:26"},{"id":29,"fname":"tester2","lname":"tester2last","phone":"11000000","email":"email2@test2.com","address":"Testaria 22","country":"TEsterio","city":"Testeriontiown","bday":"8812-09-08","username":"admin","password":"1234","access":"admin","created_at":"2018-10-14 09:16:50","updated_at":"2018-10-14 12:51:26"}][{"id":28,"fname":"tester","lname":"testlast","phone":"00000000","email":"test@email.com","address":"Tester 10","country":"TesterCountry","city":"TesterTown","bday":"2222-02-22","username":"admin","password":"1234","access":"Admin","created_at":"2018-10-13 16:34:22","updated_at":"2018-10-14 12:50:26"},{"id":29,"fname":"tester2","lname":"tester2last","phone":"11000000","email":"email2@test2.com","address":"Testaria 22","country":"TEsterio","city":"Testeriontiown","bday":"8812-09-08","username":"admin","password":"1234","access":"admin","created_at":"2018-10-14 09:16:50","updated_at":"2018-10-14 12:51:26"}]"
total_data: 2
```

Comment: Try `value['id']`. You have a typo in `$('tbody').html(cleint_data);` Can you confirm that this is not in your actual code?

Comment: There is no property `total_data` shown in the json so my guess is you aren't showing us the full response structure and that the array shown is also a property of a higher level object we can't see

Comment: I tried it that as well but nothing changes., I think its cause my array in data.table_data but I dont know where to tell it to look there.

Comment: So try  `$.each(data.table_data.....` and update question with full structure of the response and fix typo for `cleint_data`

Comment: I did try data.table_data it will not even create a row in the table,
Also that is the full stracture of data.table_data, 
        $datas = array(
                'table_data' => $output,
                'total_data' => $total_row
            );
    echo json_encode($datas);

Comment: So is what is shown in question the same as `$output`? Again, update question itself with actual json structure

Answer (score 1):

According to my observation you have two errors,
    1) Your Json result is not properly formatted.
    2) You are adding `$('tbody').html(cleint_data);`, there you misspelled the word `client_data`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
// Your json result has an error, So I corrected it and got the output. It has some unrecognized square brackets in the middle with one missing comma. check again
var yourData = jQuery.parseJSON('[{"id":"28","fname":"tester","lname":"testlast","phone":"00000000","email":"test@email.com","address":"Tester 10","country":"TesterCountry","city":"TesterTown","bday":"2222-02-22","username":"admin","password":"1234","access":"Admin","created_at":"2018-10-13 16:34:22","updated_at":"2018-10-14 12:50:26"},{"id":"29","fname":"tester2","lname":"tester2last","phone":"11000000","email":"email2@test2.com","address":"Testaria 22","country":"TEsterio","city":"Testeriontiown","bday":"8812-09-08","username":"admin","password":"1234","access":"admin","created_at":"2018-10-14 09:16:50","updated_at":"2018-10-14 12:51:26"},{"id":"28","fname":"tester","lname":"testlast","phone":"00000000","email":"test@email.com","address":"Tester 10","country":"TesterCountry","city":"TesterTown","bday":"2222-02-22","username":"admin","password":"1234","access":"Admin","created_at":"2018-10-13 16:34:22","updated_at":"2018-10-14 12:50:26"},{"id":"29","fname":"tester2","lname":"tester2last","phone":"11000000","email":"email2@test2.com","address":"Testaria 22","country":"TEsterio","city":"Testeriontiown","bday":"8812-09-08","username":"admin","password":"1234","access":"admin","created_at":"2018-10-14 09:16:50","updated_at":"2018-10-14 12:51:26"}]');

var client_data = '';
                $.each(yourData,function (key,value) {
                    client_data += '<tr>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.id +'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.fname+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.lname+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.email+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.phone+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.address+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.country+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.city+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.bday+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.username+'</td>';
                    client_data += '</tr>';
                })


                  $('tbody').html(client_data);

             //   $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Numbers do not require quotes in json and when quoted must be converted to number from string if you intend to work with them as numbers

Comment: Sorry, then it is the square brackets and a mission comma.

Comment: Rather suspect that is a question typo regarding the json and OP is likely using `json_encode()` to convert array

Comment: if we forget about his `json` typos, It clearly shows that he trying to add a variable called `cleint_data` which he didn't define in his code. it should be `client_data`

Comment: Okay so what you given me. works with your string.
so I am trying to apply it with my code, to do that I thought that I will need to      var yourData = jQuery.parseJSON(data.table_data);   (witch inside data.table_data) is a string exactly as the one you gave me. but this time the return is empty. why is that?

Comment: @Demeteor until you provide a [mcve] of the json all we will be doing is guessing

Comment: first you copy your json and paste it in http://json2csharp.com/ and try to generate and check it output as `invalid data`. Since I got errors with you json. if you get errors on that first correct on you server side code

Comment: @charlietfl correct. First provide us with a valid json result

Comment: Hey, I dont know how to provide the acutal output so I provided you with the code I use to create it. please know that a part of it its for my livesearch

Comment: Do like this, first above `var client_data = '';` add `console.log(data)` and run your application in chrome. then press `f12` and opening window you will see a `console` tab and you can see the exact output there

Comment: Even simpler is open that url in browser address bar with a valid query string and you can see the json output there

Comment: Ok I have done what you asked. (btw thanks for the console thingy learned something new today)

Comment: btw I also cant see whats is the problem with my json string or how to fix it to be totally honest

Comment: Can you add you json string to your question ? but if it has some production level sensitive information, don't do that

Comment: hello So i detected a little error. I was having output .= witch was making the json over and over again thats why a problem appeared. by removing the dot. it seems to generate valid json. in table_data. let me share it

Comment: done editing the Json on my main question. please let me know if I am posting what you needed or if am doing it wrong again

Comment: I have fixed it. the problem was indeed .= $output. 
what a single dot can do to a code ey?

Comment: yes I have posted an answer with my steps. can you check it out of its okay?
Now its working like a charm.

Comment: It is okay for sure. Because the error comes from the dataset. Hope you have learnt new stuff. cheers!! Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

okay so I would 1st like to give a huge thank you to SilentCode for the help without you I would have never figured out that my Json string was invalid, the site you shared http://json2csharp.com/ showed me where the error in my string was. so I figured out that error on the creation was inside my controller.

```
 if ($total_row > 0) {
                 foreach ($data as $row) {
                $output .= $data;
            }
```

Right here  `$output .= $data;`   with DOT EQUALS every time the string runs down each row it will add the same string over and over again. (so in case I had 100 records the string would probably be enormous)

to fix that issue all I had to do was to remove the foreach loop (its not needed I had it there when Iw as generating html inside my controller "dont do that its bad as I was told") and also replacign `.=` to just `=`

```
 if ($total_row > 0) {

                $output = $data;
            }
```

and in my view I just kept the old format I just changed `$.each(data,function...` to    `$.each(data.table_data,function...`  and everything started working normally

```
              var client_data = '';
              console.log(data);
                $.each(data.table_data,function (key,value) {
                    client_data += '<tr>';
                    client_data += '<td>' + value.id +'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.fname+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.lname+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.email+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.phone+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.address+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.country+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.city+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.bday+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.username+'</td>';
                    client_data += '<td>' +value.access+'</td>' ;

                    client_data += '<td> <a href ="users/' + value.id +'/edit" class="btn btn-outline-primary"> Edit </a> </td>' ;
                })


             $('tbody').html(client_data);
```

In conclusion my Json was being repeated for each record in my DB, and was trying to pull from the wrong part of my object (data) instead of (data.data_table)

Comment: Just a quick thing, that http://json2csharp.com/ is using to create classes from a json for `c#` language(.net development). But it can use to check validity of the `json` structure since it is validate `json` before creating classes for `c#`